# HTML 5 form input validation letters and digits

Tags: html

I need the address input to accept letter and characters ! How to?

```
<input id="Adresse" name="adresse" type="text" placeholder="Adresse" class="form-control input-md" required pattern="/[^a-zA-Z]/ "title="Only string and numbers">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<input id="Adresse" name="adresse" type="text" placeholder="Adresse" class="form-control input-md" required pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$" title="Only string and numbers">
```

This [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) can be useful too.